# Proxem Stanford Parser asp MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parsing, stanford-nlp

I'm using Proxem wrapper for Stanford Parser and I'm facing problem with Parsing in ASP.NET MVC 3 and 4 application. It throws

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an      invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at Proxem.Antelope.Parsing.Sentence.a(List`1 A_0)
 at Proxem.Antelope.Parsing.Sentence..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

In WPF and console application it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Constructor Parser(string path) is invoking constructor `Parser(string path, int poolsize)` with poolsize `value = 1`. Using constructor `Parser(string path, int poolsize)` with values -> Parser(yourPath, 0) make it work with MVC and WCF.